# Whare are the best structures for defining different levels of products or services

Tags: structure, conversion-rate

What types of product (or loyalty) structures provide the best user experience when choosing between different options or prices for a product / service?

The types of typical structures, rankings and indexers that most web sites have are:-

- Gold, Silver, Bronze
- Large, Medium, Small
- Enterprise, Business, Personal

Is there a structure that is most user friendly, or can the tone and wording affect the up sell conversion rate?

Comment: I would say for most product/service based websites, the wording affects the conversion rate. I'm not sure if your question is aimed towards UX but perhaps User Reaction on priced tiers.

Comment: I'd say user experience in UX terms doesn't come into this, just user experience in terms of the wording and how people (don't) like to be "categorized" by a site. And that is something I'd leave to the marketing/sales people... UX wise you only have to deal with the fact that there are multiple plans.

Answer (score 1):

The wording would depend greatly upon your audience. I guess there is some business information you need to gather before you make such decisions.

Let's assume a 'Small Medium Large' approach to presenting subscription options for the sake of this response.

I would first try to find out whether the business actually wants 'Small' subscribers at all - many businesses only show a 'small' option to up-sell and that if someone actually chooses it, they lose money.

Likwise, many businesses position a 'large' option out of most consumers' reach so as to better sell the option they actually want you to choose.

Take a look at these 2 links and see how obvious it is which choice THEY prefer users to make.

http://campfirenow.com/signup

https://www.ableton.com/en/push/ (scroll to the bottom)

The point I'm making is that the wording you choose and the method of presenting options depends greatly on the business need and is an example 'meeting business goals' in UX design.